# Как спрятать часть текста на CSS или кнопка"Еще"?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок в котором находится описание товара. Возможно ли сделать с помощью свойств CSS, если текст больше блока, то часть его скрывается и появляется кнопка, по нажатию на которую блок с текстом полностью открывается.
Сейчас в голове только вариант с помощью overflow: hidden и js или label, input. менять высоту блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так сделать

```css
button {outline: none;}
.text {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text:focus, button:focus ~ .text {height: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <button>Кнопка</button>
  <div class="text" tabindex="0">
    Я люблю овый год! В этот день случаются чудеса. Я желаю вам в новом году успехов, счастья, любви, много репутации на StackOverflow, новых проэктов и конечно же денег. С наступающим!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите именно кнопку, чтобы на неё кликать, то тут без js не обойтись. На чистом CSS можно сделать следующее: по умолчанию задать блоку какую-то строгую высоту и overflow: hidden, а по наведению (hover) менять высоту на auto.

```css
#block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#block:hover {
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

Comment: Можно и с помощью css сделать кнопку, так как делают модальные окна на чистом css.